# How to upgrade Mac OS X from 10.4 to 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, updates

How do I upgrade from Mac OS X 10.4 to 10.6?

I'm using an iBook G4.

Comment: Try upgrading to 10.5 instead, it supports G4 iBooks.

Answer (score 11):

You can't.  10.6 is Intel-only.  Your PPC Mac can't run it.

Comment: Leopard is the end of the line for these machines.